# Cannot load custom content type nodes with load_node_multiple or load_node

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have a custom content type called "program" that I am trying to load via a drupal module.

The .module file includes a class called Program that has a method called
`getAllPrograms()` using `include_once(drupal_get_path('module', 'progs') . '/progs.php');`

When i try and load nodes using either `node_load()` or `node_load_multiple()` i get one of two different errors randomly.

either:

> Fatal error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function user_access() in /mypath/modules/filter/filter.module on line 1035

or

> Error: Call to undefined function token_get_entity_mapping() in /mypath//sites/all/modules/contrib/token/token.tokens.inc, line 767

Note: 99% of times it is the first error, and occasionally i would recieve the token_get_entity error.

The strange thing is, while i have been trying different things to resolve the error I have been able to get both of these functions to work for a period but as soon as i clear the Drupal Cache i get the error again.

**What I have tried**

- Disabling and enabling the user module via the database.
- Checking the paths and status are correct for the main modules (system, user, block etc)
- using db_select to get a list of node ids and then use `node_load()` (with a loop) and `node_load_multiple()` to load the nodes. This is one of the things that started working for a short time until i cleared the cache.
- Tested to see if i can call `user_access()` from my .module file. This does not work and returns the same call to undefined function error.

Here is the code that I have (not progs an anonymized name)

**progs.module**

```
include_once(drupal_get_path('module', 'progs') . '/progs.php');
```

**progs.php**

```
if( !class_exists('progs') ):

    class progs 
    {
        //a bunch of properties

        function __construct()
        {
            // load partial includes and objects
            $this->load_partial_inclues();

            //retrieve all programs that are open
            $this->open_programs = Program::getAllOpenPrograms();
        }

        function load_partial_inclues()
        {
            //includes
            include_once(drupal_get_path('module', 'progs') . '/core/objects/program.php');
        }

    }

function progs()
{
    global $progs;

    if( !isset($progs) )
    {
        $progs = new progs();
    }

    return $progs;

}

// initialize
progs();

endif;
```

Note: I load the $progs into the global space so i can call it elsewhere in my module.

**program.php**

```
if( !class_exists('Program') ):

    class Program 
    {
        //a bunch of properties

        public static function getAllOpenPrograms() 
        {
             // This is the line that causes all of the issues. 
             $result = node_load_multiple('',array('type' => 'program')); 
             dpm($result);

        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you to main_menu -> Structure->Module->find new module (xxx) to check if the module activated or not ?

Comment: In which hook of your `progs.module` do you include your `progs.php`? The problem what you have is that Drupal is not yet bootstrapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Mike Vranckx mentioned, if you call `progs()` directly when you include it in progs.module, Drupal basically hasn't bootstrapped, i.e. hasn't started running fully yet. Suggest you put your `progs()` in `progs_init()` or similar so that Drupal will invoke it at the right time.

Here's a proposed way that follows your initial structure quite closely, and below you will see an alternative that better follows Drupal's conventions.

**New progs.module**

```
  /**
   * Implements hook_init().
   */
  function progs_init(){
    progs();
  }
```

**And modify your progs.php**

```
    // Why are you doing this check? Are you defining this class elsewhere in your project? If not you can safely ignore this
    //if( !class_exists('progs') ):

    // Convention is to name classes with Pascal case btw.
    class progs 
    {
        //a bunch of properties

        function __construct()
        {
            // load partial includes and objects
            $this->load_partial_inclues();

            //retrieve all programs that are open
            $this->open_programs = Program::getAllOpenPrograms();
        }

        function load_partial_inclues()
        {
            //includes
            include_once(drupal_get_path('module', 'progs') . '/core/objects/program.php');
        }

    }

    function progs()
    {
        global $progs;

        if( !isset($progs) )
        {
            $progs = new progs();
        }

        return $progs;

    }
```

---

### A more Drupal way:

**progs.module**

```
    /**
    * Implements hook_init().
    */
    function progs_init(){
        global $progs;

        // Consider using drupal_static to cache this
        if( !isset($progs) )
        {
            module_load_include('inc', 'progs', 'progs');
            $progs = new Progs();
        }
    }
```

**progs.inc (convention is to use .inc)**

```
    class Progs 
    {
        //a bunch of properties

        function __construct()
        {
            // load partial includes and objects
            $this->load_partial_inclues();

            //retrieve all programs that are open
            $this->open_programs = Program::getAllOpenPrograms();
        }

        function load_partial_inclues()
        {
            //includes
            module_load_include('php', 'progs', 'core/objects/program');
        }

    }
```